# Good java tokenizers?

Tags: java, tokenize

I am curious about any good tokenizers out there for java OTHER THAN those included in the standard libs such as StreamTokenizer and StringTokenizer, which in my opinion are not very good.

The only one I know of is [jTopas](http://jtopas.sourceforge.net/jtopas/index.html), which is excellent. So, what else is out there?

***Lets exclude ANTLR from suggestions. Also, I know writing one from scratch is fairly easy, but having done so a few times I found that I prefer to use something generic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what ways do you find the default tokenizers poor?  (will help to answer your question)

Comment: I have a library you might find useful https://github.com/mtimmerm/dfalex

Answer (score 0):

I really like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), although it may be quite heavyweight if you only need to perform tokenisation - but it's great if you need a lexer/parser, particularly in Java.

Comment: I almost excluded ANTLR from suggestions, because of exactly what you mentioned.

Comment: Also, the source code/script files I find myself parsing are generally simple enough that using ANTLR would take more time than doing one by hand, for example: https://github.com/jdc0589/jTranslate/blob/master/test/testGrammars/parseTest.jtg

Comment: Righteo - just thought I'd throw it out there. Thanks for your mention of jTopas by the way, which looks quite nice.

Comment: @jdc0589, @sharky, ANTLR can also be used to generate only a tokenizer without a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is included in the jdk, have you looked at [java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? I have also used [JFlex](http://jflex.de/) some time ago and found it quite good.

Comment: Did not know about jFlex, will take a look.